# How to get the content owned by the currently logged-in user?

Tags: 7, redirection, users

A user is the owner of only one node, and I want to redirect the user, at login time, to his only owned node.

How can I get the node content if I know only the logged-in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have do it:

```
function MYHOOK_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
    global $user;
    $nid = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchField();
    drupal_goto('node/' . $nid);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **hook_user_login** -> http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7. This is where you can add your own custom code to do things like look up the node ID (nid) by user ID (uid) and then issue a **drupal_goto** (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

There's also the option of doing the customization with **hook_form_alter** to the login form which might be considered more of a D6 solution. You'll have to provide more details if these suggestions are not addressing your question.

Comment: this is the issues how to look up the node ID (nid) by user ID (uid) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$nid = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type', array(':uid' => $user->uid, ':type' => $node_type))->fetchField():
```

This will get you the nid.

Comment: As I there is just on node content per user I don't think is necessarily to set also the type. I have tested the query's to see which one is faster and the result was the same `Query took 0.0002 sec`.

Comment: Are you sure that users will only ever have a single node they created? I'd suggest to add the type condition, just to be sure.

Comment: In my case it is sure that they will have only one node created, because they have no right to create nodes, only to view and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: please disregard this answer (see the comments for why).

```
$nid = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.uid', $user->uid)
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->fetchField()
```

I'd be tempted to do it this way since it's more the 'Drupal' way, although the other suggestions are certainly valid. Note that I've put a limit on the SQL statement for safety.

Comment: db_select() is 30% slower then db_query() should only be used if there is a reason for it. Reasons include that you need paging/tablesort, have dynamic queries or need stuff like node_access.

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't know that. Do you have a link to some benchmarks for this 30% slowdown? I'd like to know more about this!

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1067802. It's not surprising, SelectQuery is an OOP abstraction layer with lots of string mangling and many, many method calls on top of db_query()

Comment: Thanks for this. I will start my own question to take this a bit further.